# Collection of subgroups

Tags: group-theory, elementary-set-theory, category-theory

The question revolves around a statement like the following:

> Let $G_\lambda \  (\lambda \in \Lambda)$ be subgroups of $G$...

How do I collect subgroups of $G$ in a mathematically precise manner? Do I interpret $G_\lambda \ (\lambda\in \Lambda)$ as a *function*
\begin{align}
\lambda \mapsto G_\lambda
\end{align}
such that for each $\lambda \in \Lambda$, where $\Lambda$ is some index set, I get a unique subgroup of $G$, denoted by $G_\lambda$. But then if I interpret it as a function, what is its codomain?

Or do I interpret $G_\lambda \ (\lambda \in \Lambda) $ as 
$$
\lambda \mapsto \tau_\lambda \in \text{Mor}(H,G)
$$
where 
$$
\tau_\lambda : H \to G
$$
a monomorphism in the category of groups? (monomorphism, in fact,  for then $\tau_\lambda(G_\lambda)$ is indeed a subgroup of $G$).

Finally, I would like to be able to understand the following statement:

> Let A be any **subset** (not subgroup) of a group $G$. The intersection of all subgroups of $G$ which contain $A$ itself contains $A$ and is the subgroup of $G$ generated by $A$.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2574355/169085

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is usually referred to as a *family* which is exactly the same thing as a function.

Its codomain is $\{G_\lambda, \lambda\in \Lambda\}$, which is a set according to the axiom scheme of replacement. Alternatively, you could say its codomain is $\mathcal{P}(G)$, the powerset of $G$, or if you want the image $\{H\in \mathcal{P}(G)\mid\exists \lambda, H= G_\lambda\}$.

The last statement has not much to do with the previous question. It just says that for any subset $A\subset G$, there is a *least* subgroup of $G$ that contains it, usually called the subgroup *generated* by $A$. There are often different descriptions of this subgroup in terms of $A$.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. How are we assured that there exists a function $\Lambda \to \mathcal{P}(G)$ that picks up all the subgroups of $G$ which contain $A$?

Comment: @EEEB As Max states, the last statement doesn't have much to do with what you had before it. While you can make such a function, there's no need to. The (carrier of the) subgroup of $G$ generated by $A$ is $\bigcap\{H\in\mathcal{P}(G)\mid A\subseteq H\land\mathsf{SubgroupOf}((H,\cdot|_{H\times H}),(G,\cdot))\}$ where $\mathsf{SubgroupOf}((H,\star),(G,\cdot))$ is a formalization in first-order logic of the statement "$(H,\star)$ is a subgroup of $(G,\cdot)$" (exercise). So we only need a set of subgroups, not a family, and the axiom of separation gives us this (and also $\bigcap$).