# Family of vector spaces

Tags: vector-spaces, category-theory

I am interested in the following expression

"Let $W_i (i\in I)$ be a family of vector spaces..."

I came to understand, that this means **the same thing as** "that there is a function from an index set $I$
$$
W:I\to \mathbf{Vect}
$$
which "picks out" the required vector spaces." (in other words $W_i(i\in I)$ tells me to view the entire function $W:I \to \mathbf{Vect}$, not only its image.)

What I am unsure about is what the codomain space is. What is the space of all vector spaces? Or should I view the above $W$ as a functor rather than a function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could view it as a functor from the set $I$ viewed as a discrete category into the category of vector spaces. This neatly hides away some set-theoretic concerns.

Alternatively, in a typical set-theoretic context, a function is (or can be) identified with its graph, so the function representing the family $W$ is just a set of $I$-many pairs whose second components are vector spaces. An individual vector space is (usually) a set by definition, so this is completely fine set-theoretically.

Since the class of all vector spaces is a proper class, you can't (in ZFC) say $W\in (I\to\mathbf{Vect})$, but you can say $\mathsf{dom}(W)=I \land \forall i\in I. \mathsf{isVectSpace}(W(i))$ where $\mathsf{isVectSpace}$ is the predicate representing the class $\mathbf{Vect}$. Abstracting from $W$ (and also $I$ if you want), this gives you a predicate specifying that $W$ is a $I$-indexed family of vector spaces. This predicate represents the proper<sup>*</sup> class of $I$-indexed families of vector spaces. (Many people notationally overload $\in$ to also be used for membership in a class. Alternatively, in many set theories other than ZFC $\in$ does operate on classes or their analogues, but $I\to\mathbf{Vect}$ wouldn't mean anything. And then there are set theories (often used for the definition of categories) where there'd be almost no issue at all: you'd have a large set of vector spaces with small sets as carriers and the set of functions from a small set to a large set is a perfectly well-defined large set.)

To be clear, there are no set-theoretic concerns with the family $W$, only with the "collection" of all $I$-indexed families of vector spaces, i.e. the "collection" $W$ and things like it would be a "member" of.

<sup>*</sup> Assuming $I\neq\emptyset$, otherwise it's just the singleton set containing the empty function.

Answer (score 2):

You have a set $I$, and for each $i \in I$ you have a vector space. Don't overthink it. While category theory has its place, there is very little motivation for thinking of every statement like this in terms of functors and categories.

Answer (score 1):

Don't look too far. A *family* $\bigl(W_i\bigr)_{i\in I}$ of vector spaces is created as soon as  each teaching assistant $i\in I$ has selected a vector space $W_i$ in some way. You don't have to think of the universe of all vector spaces and an actual map, or production scheme, $I\to{\bf vect}, \ i\mapsto W_i$ here. This "map"  is pretty arbitrary, maybe "nonconstructible", and nobody asks about continuity and such. It only serves to organize the collection $\bigl(W_i\bigr)_{i\in I}\>$.

Comment: Couldn't one conceivably care about continuity of such sorts of maps, for example in the case of a manifold, where $p \mapsto T_pM$?